# Is it possible to tell Spring Security how my user and authority schemes look like without raw SQL queries?

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have columns *nickname*, *password*, *enabled* and *authority* in my *user* scheme. Column *authority* is a foreign key to scheme *authority*.
I have columns *authority* in my *authority* scheme.

My schemes are different from those Spring Security waits by default.
That's why I have to write this code in configuration.

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsManager users(DataSource dataSource) {
    JdbcUserDetailsManager users = new JdbcUserDetailsManager(dataSource);
    users.setUsersByUsernameQuery(
            "SELECT nickname, CONCAT('{noop}', password), true " +
                    "FROM \"user\" WHERE nickname = ?"
    );
    users.setAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery(
            "SELECT u.nickname, a.authority " +
                    "FROM authority a " +
                    "LEFT JOIN \"user\" u " +
                    "ON a.authority=u.authority WHERE nickname = ?"
    );
    return users;
}
```

It works well. But I think it is not the best solution because of the raw SQL queries in my code.

Is there a way not to write SQL queries?

---

I also use Spring Data JPA in my project.

I an idea have to write my implementation of AuthenticatedProvider and use UserService inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The image is from: **Spring Security In Action by Laurentiu Spilca.**

You could always implement the interface/contract **UserDetailsService** https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html

and load users with model classes that also implements another interface/contract **UserDetails**.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html

and **configure your UserDetailsService as a bean so that AuthenticationProvider could retrieve at run time(autowired). You should also provide a PasswordEncoder in the same configuration class as a bean.** [***No need to implement a provider if you use default authentication logic***(compare passwords from db and given password by using a password encoder)]

Your database schema should allow you to provide the information contained in UserDetails service contract/interface.

NOTE: GrantedAuthorities starting with ROLE_ are identified as roles.